# How to add command event and pass the current node data in wpf telerik RadTreeviewItem with custom button

Tags: wpf, events, telerik, radtreeview, custom-button

I'm using Kendo Telerik `RadTreeView` control in WPF.. I have functionality that for each `RadTreeViewItem`, I need to show a button, which i able to do.

Now the button next to each `RadTreeViewItem` will have event/command which need to open pop window and pass the current node data.

I have tried with code behind button click event and it works fine.. but as per the requirement we should only use command not code behind events.

Here is the code where I'm adding the button..

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BuildingStructure"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding StructureLevels}"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource levelNodeStyle}">

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="3*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                       Width="250"
                       Text="{Binding Name}" 
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            <Button
                Panel.ZIndex="100"
                BorderThickness="0"
                BorderBrush="Transparent"
                Background="Black"
                Grid.Column="1"
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                Margin="0 2 0 5">
                <Image
                    Width="20"
                    Height="20"
                   Source="/Project;component/Resources/Images/03-Add.png"/>

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestRadTreeCommand}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Please check the image for your Reference :

[image]

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: The `Button` has a `Command` property so there is no reason to use an `EventTrigger` and an `InvokeCommandAction` to handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event. Where is the `TestRadTreeCommand` defined?

Comment: `TestRadTreeCommand` is defined in ViewModel, i tried with Command  property but its does not get called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Button` has a `Command` property so there is no reason to use an `EventTrigger` and an `InvokeCommandAction` to handle the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event.

If `TestRadTreeCommand` is defined in the view model, i.e. the `DataContext` of the `TreeView`, you could bind to it like this:

```
<Button
    Panel.ZIndex="100"
    BorderThickness="0"
    BorderBrush="Transparent"
    Background="Black"
    Grid.Column="1"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Margin="0 2 0 5"
    Command="{Binding DataContext.TestRadTreeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}}">
    <Image Width="20"
           Height="20"
           Source="/CCRIS;component/Resources/Images/03-Add.png"/>
</Button>
```

Comment: as you see the i'm adding command , i need to add parameter to it.. the parameter should contain data of that node.. how can i achieve that. Thanks  in advance

Comment: How is this related to your *original* question? Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Don't ask additional questions in the comments field.

Comment: ok  i will, but sometime everything does go in one direction,, somethings in comes in between............

Comment: Yes and i got the desired output